# Mkdir doesn't work whilst trying to un-tar using JTar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a function that un-tars a file. Below is the code I have written using JTar

```
    private void untar(String tarFile, String destFolder) throws IOException {
            TarInputStream tis = new TarInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tarFile)));
            TarEntry entry;
            while (( entry = tis.getNextEntry() ) != null) {
                System.out.println( "Extracting: " + entry.getName() );
                int count;
                byte data[] = new byte[2048];

                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    new File( destFolder + "/" + entry.getName() ).mkdirs();
                    continue;
                } else {
                    int di = entry.getName().lastIndexOf( '/' );
                    System.out.println("File"+di);
                    if (di != -1) {
                        File f = new File( destFolder + "/" + entry.getName().substring( 0, di ) );
                        if(f.mkdirs())
                            System.out.println(f.isDirectory());
                    }
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( destFolder + "/" + entry.getName() );
                BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream( fos );

                while (( count = tis.read( data ) ) != -1) {
                    dest.write( data, 0, count );
                }

                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
            }
            tis.close();
        }
```

When I hit the mkdirs() part and try to create a directory it does not do so, and I cannot see any output on console after the `if` statement.

Possibly this is the reason that the subsequent code for FileOutputStream shows an IOexception stating not a directory.

I can't find a solution for this problem anywhere.

Comment: mkdirs() will return true or false. You are not checking the return value and act on it. Moreover you should only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. Check with exists(). mkdirs() will return false if the directory already exists. That why you cant call it blindly as you do now.

Comment: `Regarding android permissions, I have added that in AndroidManifests.xml so that must not be a problem` That is not enough. You should also add code to ask the user at runtime to confirm those permissions. Google for runtime permissions.

Comment: If you cannot create the directory then stop or return. It makes no sense trying to write a file in a non existing directory.

Comment: For the time beeing (as quick test) you could go to the settengs for your app on the device and toggle the storage permission to on.